# Exact target automation question. Write into Description field in Salesforce after a click on an EDM

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation

I have an automated process which sends an EDM to a visitor who has registered into our website. Data is passed from the web form into Salesforce and creates a lead. Exact target then sends an EDM to the lead with further info and some links. 
I want that when the lead clicks on a link, this information is then passed into the "Description" field in his Lead contact inside Salesforce.

I need help, please. 
Thanks!

Comment: Any code to share that you have tried so far?

Comment: No, I haven't used any code at all. I have very little experience with AMP Script.

Comment: Hi there? any help please? Thanks.

Comment: https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/functions.html